# Convert json object to input field

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter

I'm attempting to reach a target, i don't know if i take the correct way.
I use Codeigniter to insert form data in database. I have one drop down field, below some input fields can be displayed according the value selected in the drop down. The drop down and the input fields are linked. The way i try to realize that makes me need to convert json object to input fields because after making a selection in the drop down result appear like this:

```
[{"name":"NSS"},{"name":"POLIZA"},{"name":"CARNET"}]
```

How can I convert the result above to :

```
<input  type="text" name="NSS">
<input  type="text" name="POLIZA">
<input  type="text" name="CARNET">
```

Below is the way i attempt to realise it:

I- FORM VIEW.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('admin/save');?>" >

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Seguro médico</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <select name="seguro_medico" id="seguro_medico">
        <option></option>
        <?php 
        foreach($seguro_medico as $row)
            echo '<option value="'.$row->id_ap.'">'.$row->medical_insurance.'</option>';
      ?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="seguro_input">
    <?php 
    if (isset($GET_INPUT)) {
        foreach($GET_INPUT as $get_input) {
    ?>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label><?=$get_input->name;?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input  type="text" name="<?=$get_input->name;?>" >
            </div>
          </div>
    <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" name="send_citas" value="Send">

</form>
```

II- JQUERY CODE.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#seguro_medico").on('change',function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo site_url('admin/get_input');?>',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'seguro_medico='+$("#seguro_medico").val(),
            success: function(data) {
                $("#seguro_input").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

III- THE CONTROLLER (get_input).

```
public function get_input() {

    $seguro_medico=$this->input->post('seguro_medico');
    $query = $this->model_admin->get_input($seguro_medico);
    $data['GET_INPUT'] =$query;
    echo json_encode($query);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `get_input`function is returning a json object, so...

1. You have to set that dataType in your $.ajax call.
2. In the success function, you can take the json object array and loop it to write all the corresponding inputs, maintaining the container divs.

Putting all together...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#seguro_medico").on('change',function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo site_url('admin/get_input');?>',
            type: 'post',
            data: { seguro_medico: $("#seguro_medico").val() },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {

                var inputs = [];

                $.each(data,function(id,value) {
                    inputs.push(
                        '<div class="form-group">' +
                          '<label>' + value.name + '</label>' +
                          '<div class="col-sm-6">' +
                            '<input type="text" name="' + value.name + '">' +
                          '</div>' +
                        '</div>'
                    );
                });

                $("#seguro_input").html(inputs.join(''));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much it's exactly what I need. But now how can i pass the input field name to the controller that save the form to  database ? Like 'input1' => $this->input->post('input1')

Comment: Yes, that's it. If you submit the form with a POST, in your controller you'll receive one post variable for each input.

Comment: I tried like:  public function save()
{
$save = array(
  'seguro_medico'  => $this->input->post('seguro_medico')
  )
}. I don't know how to post the input values.